# wordpress plugin upload failed

Tags: wordpress, plugins

when I try to upload a plugin then it shows the following message:

'Could not create directory. /home/content/76/5451076/html/wp-content/plugins/e-mailit/

Plugin install failed."
please help.
Best regards,
Rip

Comment: Make sure about permissions to create a directory in your server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the permissions are set. If it is set, then set a maximum upload size in your php.ini file which is above the size of the plugin.